# SQL Server - Query to display person and his bank name is a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables to deal with:

**TRANS**

```
ID       HPARENT1       HPERSON
--------------------------------
70001    60001          100
60001    50001          100
50001    NULL             2
```

where

1. `ID` starting with 7 is a charge
2. `ID` starting with 6 is a receipt
3. `ID` starting with 5 is the bank deposit entry in the same `TRANS` table

Here in this example, 70001 is a charge paid by the receipt 60001 and 50001 is the bank deposit entry of the receipt.

`HPERSON` of a charge and receipt is the person to whom it was charged and paid by.

Where as, `HPERSON` of a bank deposit entry is the BANK's ID.

**BANK**

```
ID       BankName
--------------------------
2        MyBank
```

**PERSON**

```
ID       FIRSTNAME       LASTNAME
---------------------------------
100      Barry           Allen
```

What I want in the output to include the person name and his bank's name.

```
Barry Allen       MyBank
```

And the way to identify person's bank is, find his deposit entry (50001) then find the hperson (2) from it (which is bank's id)

I guess I will have to join the table TRANS with itself.

Not sure how.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Those "starting with"-tricks...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Pretty sure you'd be able to work something out using `SUBSTRING` but to be honest I'd throw this data model away and start again.  If you're looking at any kind of volume it's never going to work fast even if it wasn't crap to begin with (which it is).

Comment: I have a feeling you're not using the right tables. Talk with your team leader or your more experienced colleagues. Or better yet, look for a "detail" table, you should never end up triple joining **trans**. (*insider hint*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join a table to itself by giving the different "versions" aliases like this. I am assuming there are only 3 levels of this hierarki.

```
SELECT
  p.FIRSTNAME, p.LASTNAME, b.BankName
FROM
  PERSON p
JOIN
  TRANS t1
ON t1.HPERSON = p.id
JOIN
  TRANS t2
ON t2.ID = t1.HPARENT1
JOIN
  TRANS t3
ON t3.ID = t2.HPARENT1
JOIN
  BANK b
ON
  b.ID = t3.HPERSON
```